# How to crawl the specific web site by scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl [this site](https://aaav2.hinet.net/A1/AuthScreen.jsp) by scrapy shell, I had tried:

`$ scrapy shell 'https://aaav2.hinet.net/A1/AuthScreen.jsp'`

and plus user agent

```
$ scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2
Safari/601.3.9' 'https://aaav2.hinet.net/A1/AuthScreen.jsp'
```

then `view(response)` but got nothing.

Would anyone help me to get correct `view(response)`, 
just like I open this URL directly in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting to another URL. Do:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://aaav2.hinet.net/A1/error.jsp?aa-eurl=edc68fe62571d6617ef5f42113d9068aa9f6600e320d55084d75fbf2cd244155e02b9b684284ed94c52ee591d2edde9a&mesg=aa-version+parameter+is+required%21%3Cbr+%2F%3Eaa-productid+parameter+is+required%21%3Cbr+%2F%3Eaa-curl+parameter+is+required%21%3Cbr+%2F%3Eaa-eurl+parameter+is+required%21%3Cbr+%2F%3Eaa-fee+parameter+is+required%21%3Cbr+%2F%3E&aa-eurlDesc=&aa-device=pc&aa-usage=&aa-propertiesKey=&aa-language="
```

`view(response)` of this will show you a page just like your browser.

Comment: you are right! Mr.Piron, I have another trouble, when I tried to $scrapy shell 'https://www.ttt.nat.gov.tw/Default.aspx?view=0' , another error happened again. Could you help me to fix this out?

Comment: You want to get data from first URL or redirected one? and what kind of data you want? @magicpony

Comment: Mr. Piron, what data I want is the form in this url 'https://www.ttt.nat.gov.tw/Default.aspx?view=0',
however, when I click it, it redirect me to 
'https://aaav2.hinet.net/A1/AuthScreen.jsp',
therefore, in my first question, I gave the wrong url  ; (
appreciate your patience

Comment: take a look at [how to stop redirect](https://www.ttt.nat.gov.tw/Default.aspx?view=0) to see how to prevent redirecting and in the shell you can do fetch(url, redirect=False)